# How do dielectric molecules in a liquid phase align when polarized?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, electric-fields, material-science, dielectric

[image]

As seen in the diagram, when a dielectric material becomes electrically polarized, the molecules align themselves in a manner where the respective charges are parallel to each other horizontally.

However, this diagram shows a solid dielectric, and are fixed in place. How would a liquid dielectric’s molecule align themselves are they are in motion and rotate? Would a strong enough field fixate them as in the diagram below?

Comment: At any given instant in time, would you expect something fundamentally different from the picture shown above?